# как правильно расположить картинки htn

Tags: html, css

[image]

не могу понять почему третья картинка так низко она должна быть прям под второй как правильно изменить положение вот мой код

```css
IMG.fig {
  float: right;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<a rel="simplebox3" href="#">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TONtg.jpg" alt="..." style="width:300px;height:300px;">
</a>
<a rel="simplebox3" href="#">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TONtg.jpg" alt="..." style="width:300px;height:130px;" class="fig">
</a>
<a rel="simplebox3" href="#">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TONtg.jpg" alt="..." style="width:300px;height:130px;" class="fig">
</a>
```

не может быть абсолютным позиционированным элементом так как это лента новостей и там расположение картинок подстраиваются под текст

Comment: Пожалуйста, организуйте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), в частности дайте исходные картинки и уберите php-код, так решить проблему будет проще

Comment: картинки постоянно будут меняться так как это лента новостей @andreymal

Comment: Но воспроизводимый пример со всеми нужными стилями и без php-кода всё равно организуйте, помогающим (в том числе мне) будет лень удалять его каждый раз самостоятельно, чтобы воспроизвести вашу проблему

Comment: если я правильно вас понял то все готово @andreymal

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/58q7cbyn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для всех img добавьте img{float:left;} а для IMG.fig {float: right;}

```css
   IMG.fig {
    float: right;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
   }
   img{float:left;}
```

```html
<a rel="simplebox3" href="https://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/userpic/6/7/8/av-656876.jpg">
        <img src="https://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/userpic/6/7/8/av-656876.jpg" alt="..." style="width:300px;height:300px;">
        </a>
        <a rel="simplebox3" href="https://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/userpic/6/7/8/av-656876.jpg">
        <img src="https://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/userpic/6/7/8/av-656876.jpg" alt="..." style="width:300px;height:130px;" class="fig">
        </a>
        <a rel="simplebox3" href="https://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/userpic/6/7/8/av-656876.jpg">
        <img src="https://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/userpic/6/7/8/av-656876.jpg" alt="..." style="width:300px;height:130px;" class="fig">
        </a>
```

Comment: а можно сделать так чтоб при уменьшении экрана картинки не меняли своей позиции

Comment: но они могут уменьшаться

Comment: тогда припишите ширину в % а не в пикселях

Comment: вот теперь все работает спасибо вам большое